# Is there a way to install a module named google in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I try to create a speech-to-text transcriber with Python and Google cloud.

Unfortunately, it always gives me the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'".

I installed plenty of packages, google-cloud, google-cloud-storage and many more and nothing seems to work.

I also looked up "How to install Python packages", but after following the respective links, which I though must be the right ones, it still did not work.

The following is part of the code I use:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io
import os
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1 import types
import wave
from google.cloud import storage


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' # This is the error I receive

I installed the following packages on the project:
astroid==2.3.3
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.0
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
gcloud==0.18.3
google-api-core==1.17.0
google-api-python-client==1.8.0
google-auth==1.14.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
google-cloud-storage==1.27.0
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
grpcio==1.28.1
httplib2==0.17.2
idna==2.9
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
more-itertools==8.2.0
oauth2client==4.1.3
packaging==20.3
pep8==1.7.1
pluggy==0.13.1
protobuf==3.11.3
py==1.8.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pydub==0.23.1
pylint==2.4.4
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==5.4.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.9
wcwidth==0.1.9
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Regarding my OS, I work on a Win10x64 and tried the code on VS 2019 and PyCharm.

Also, opening a new project did not work, yet.

I am totally lost. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `pip install google`

Comment: How do you know you’ve installed it?

Comment: You need to look up "How to install a Python package".  There may well be a specific version under the google package instructions.  We expect you to do such research before posting here.

Comment: A lot depends on how you installed it. For instance, google suggests pip install into a virtual environment. In that case, you need to activate the environment when you run the program so that python can find the modules. To answer this question we will need to know which operating system you are on, how you installed google and how you run your script.

Comment: There are plenty of resources available on how to install and use libraries in Python, in what way do those not apply to this particular situation?

Comment: Edit your question and include the output from `pip freeze`. I recommend using `virtualenv` and creating a clean project and virtual environment. Then `pip install -U google-cloud-speech`. `pip freeze` will then show only the modules installed as part of that package installation. You could have other packages installed that prevent the Google libraries from installing (or updating). Note: do NOT install the package `google`. That package is deprecated.

Comment: I installed the google-cloud-speech and everything I wrote in the updated question. I will try the virtualenv, but the rest did not work, yet. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this page: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python ?

And have you tried `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's always helpful to elaborate on what you think the user might be missing rather than insert a link.

Comment: Yes, I tried this. Unfortunately, it did not help. :/

Comment: @Toplasch It sounds like your `python` and `pip` do not belong to the same install and/or environment. As an alternative to `virtualenv` - that tdelaney mentioned above - you may also want to take a look at  [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) which comes with [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to manage your environments. I personally found it easier to manage them with Anaconda/conda on both Linux and Windows - especially when working with machine learning or deep learning.

Comment: Also to whoever downvoted my answer: Could please let me know what is wrong with my answer (considering the information known about the issue by then)?

Comment: @CibinJoseph What I thought the user was missing? I did clearly put the `pip install google-cloud-speech` in my answer. By the time I posted the answer google-cloud-speech was not listed as installed.

Comment: @OliverMaerz Thanks, it worked with the virtualenv in anaconda.